# Scala Spark/Databricks: Efficiently load multiple partitions with different schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have data that's partitioned as year/month/day. I want to be able to load an arbitrary date range - a start date and end date, rather than just a particular day/month/year. The data has mildly different schema for different days.

I can load only a single item at a single level - like, "2020", "July 2020" or "July 1st, 2020". This is fast, and with `mergeschema = true` any schema issues will be handled for me. But, I can't choose to load a particular week or other arbitrary range that goes across partitions.

I can load at the top level with `"mergeschema = true"`, convert the year/month/day fields to a single `date` column and filter on that column. This can do arbitrary ranges, handles the schema issue but is slow, as it looks at *all* the data without benefiting from the partitioning. It will also fail if there are schema issues that can't be handled with mergeschema, even if those only exist outside of the range I'm loading. (For instance, if I'm trying to load a week in the middle of July, but there's badly-formatted data in April, it will fail if I try to load and then filter.)

I can programatically figure out the set of partitions that correspond to the date range in question, load them and union them together. This is fast and will only look at the data it needs to load, but the union call fails if there are schema differences.

I'm on the verge of writing a "MergeSchema" function myself so that I can union different dataframes and add null columns where needed (as would happen if I'd loaded with "mergeschema"), but this feels like a really awkward and difficult solution to what seems like a simple problem.

What's the correct way to handle this? I can't change the sources I'm loading from, they're handled by other teams a long way away from me.

Answer (score 0):

use brackets or braces :
"2020/07/[1-7]" or
"2020/07/{1,2,3,4...}"

```
basePath='s3://some-bucket/year=2020/'
paths = [
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=06/day=2[6-9]',
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=06/day=30',
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=07/day=[1-3]',
    
]
df = spark.read.option("basePath", basePath).json(paths)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the mechanics of that work out too, but it won't work for arbitrary ranges, will it? Like, I couldn't do 2020/06/26 - 2020/07/03

Comment: I'm not the best with regex, but you could do something with that. or you could script your paths based on the dates. and then read in the different paths. `basePath='s3://some-bucket/year=2020/'
paths = [
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=06/day=2[6-9]',
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=06/day=30',
    's3://some-bucket/year=2020/month=07/day=[1-3]',
    
]
df = spark.read.option("basePath", basePath).json(paths)`